# Example of an *associative* function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous in both variables but fails to be continuous

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology

A classical example of a function of two variables continuous in each but which fails to be continuous is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/504787/354508). I wonder if someone can suggest an example of an *associative* counterexample of a binary operation continuous in each variable which fails to be continuous (it doesn't have to be on $\mathbb{R}$ but I expect that to be the easiest setting for analytic examples).

Context: I am currently working with topological monoids, and have found (for a fixed multiplication) a canonical topology related to an action of the monoid which guarantees that the multiplication is continuous in each variable. I would of course like the topology to make it fully continuous, but a priori it is not clear that this holds.

Comment: Of course, a proof that associativity bridges the gap and forces such a function to be continuous would equally be a valid response.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the definition here should be $f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))$: $f$ is an associative binary operation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's associativity of function composition.

Comment: There is a whole field of semi/quasi/pseudotopological groups that have group operations that are continuous only in one variable separately but not simultaneously (or continuous group operation but discontinuous inverse etc.). See Arhangel'skij and Tkachenko's recent book on topological algebraic structures ("topological groups and related structures").

Comment: @jmerry have replaced "function" with "operation" to mitigate confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very natural example is addition with $\infty$.  Let $X=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, topologized as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ (more generally, we could replace $\mathbb{R}$ with any locally compact group that is not compact).  Consider the addition operation $+:X\times X\to X$, where any sum involving $\infty$ is defined to be $\infty$.  Then it is easy to see that $+$ is continuous separately in each variable, and is associative.  But it is not jointly continuous; for instance as $x\to\infty$, $(x,-x)\to(\infty,\infty)$, but $x+(-x)=0$ does not converge to $\infty+\infty=\infty$.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the kind of counterexample I wanted. Compared with topological groups, perhaps we get pathological things happening when a monoid has an element (in this case a zero element, $\infty$) with neighbourhoods which aren't translates via the monoid multiplication of neighbourhoods of the identity.